# Why would a Windows 2003 server clock reset during a reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2003, time

After a reboot the windows time reset itself to 26 March 2007. This meant it could not connect to any other servers in the domain. We have set the time to the correct value but we are having intermittent NetBios name problems. I want to understand whether the clock resetting is a red herring or a clue to the problem.

Comment: what is in the event log?

Comment: Nothing of a note, apart from the event times. It just did its shut down events with correct time signature and then the start up events were at the March 2007 time.

Answer (score 7):

Is the hardware clock set correctly?

You could also have a dead BIOS battery, causing the hardware clock to reset to a default if the power is removed.

Comment: I second. I would suggest looking at the hardware clock and CMOS battery as the culprit here.

Comment: There's no reason not to fix the battery issue (should be less than $5), and then deal with any other issues afterward, if they persist.  That's an odd time, though - I expect to see 1980 on a dead battery.

Comment: Seems to be especially a problem on VMs when the host time is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem that occurred whenever windows updates would run and sit for a while before the required reboot. The clock would always reset to midnight. It drove me nuts, and always killed our database replication.

The only solution we were able to find was to disable automatic updates. Now we manually run updates and reboot immediately. (And are in the process of moving the content to a new virtual Windows 2008 Server).

Comment: This happened to my server last night and cost me an hour of time-shifting invoices, payments, jobs and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Could that be related to the DST Timezone change that happened in 2007?  some weird patches can cause this...and the date fits